# in my project how can i set http session tracking login time for 30 second only

Tags: python, django

In my project i want to set HTTP Session tracking  for 30 second after 30 second user should be logout automatically, if user is not doing any think and also one more condition after login if user click on back button of my browser and than forward button of my browser than it must be transfer on login page for entering username and password.

**Views.py**

```
    from django.shortcuts import render
    from django.http import HttpResponse
    from django.template import RequestContext
    from .models import Reg
    from .forms import LoginForm
    from .forms import RegForm

    def reg(request):
            if request.method == 'POST':
             form = RegForm(request.POST)
             if form.is_valid():
                form.save(commit=True)
                return HttpResponse('reg success')
             else:
                print(form.errors)
                return HttpResponse("error")
            else:
              form = RegForm()
              return render(request,'reg.html', {'form': form})
    def login(request):
        if request.method == "POST":
            MyLoginForm = LoginForm(request.POST)
            if MyLoginForm.is_valid():
                un =MyLoginForm.cleaned_data['user']
                pw=MyLoginForm.cleaned_data['pwd']
                dbuser = Reg.objects.filter(user=un,pwd=pw)
                if not dbuser:
                    return HttpResponse('opppppss login faield')
                else:
                    return HttpResponse('login success')
        else:
            form = LoginForm()
            return render(request, 'login.html', {'form': form})
    def home(request):
        return render(request,'home.html')
```

**models.py**

```
    from __future__ import unicode_literals
    from django.db import models

    class Reg(models.Model):
        user = models.CharField(primary_key=True,max_length=20)
        pwd = models.CharField(max_length=20)
        fname=models.CharField(max_length=10)
        lname=models.CharField(max_length=10)
        dob=models.DateField()
        mobno=models.IntegerField()

    forms.py
    from django import forms
    from .models import Reg

    class RegForm(forms.ModelForm):
        class Meta:
            password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)
            model = Reg
            widgets = {'pwd': forms.PasswordInput(),}
            fields = ['user', 'pwd','fname','lname','dob','mobno']

    class LoginForm(forms.Form):
        user = forms.CharField(max_length=20)
        pwd = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput())
```

**home.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    </html>
    <html>
    <body bgcolor="#00ffff">
    <h1>welcome </h1>
    <a href="./reg">click here to register</a><br>
    <a href="./login">click here to login</a>
    </body>
    </html>

    login.html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <form action="" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form }}
        <br>
        <input type="submit" value="submit">
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>

    reg.html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <form action="" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form }}
        <br>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding this to your **settings.py**

```
SESSION_COOKIE_AGE = 30
```

Comment: if user click on back button of my browser and than forward button of my browser than it must be transfer on login page for entering username and password.